# 'find path -name "test*" system command using Popen not working

Tags: python, unix, find

I am trying to use the `-name` option for `find` and I am not getting any results.
I get results when running the exact same command at the Unix command prompt.
Without the -name option the results are returned as expected. Other options such as `-mmin` work fine too.
I think this has to do with the quote escaping but I can't figure out a workaround.

Here is the function I use to run the command:

```
def run_cmd(cmd, strict=True):
    """
    Runs a system command and returns the return code, stdout and stderr.

    :param cmd: system command to be run
    :param strict: throws error if set else return silently
    :return: return code, stdout, stderr
    :raises RuntimeError if execution fails
    """

    cmd = validate_cmd_type(cmd)

    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)

    (out, err) = p.communicate()

    out = '\n'.join(out.decode("utf-8").split('\n'))
    err = '\n'.join(err.decode("utf-8").split('\n'))

    _logger.info("returned code = %d" % p.returncode)

    if len(out) > 0:
        _logger.info("Standard output:\n\n%s\n" % out)
    else:
        _logger.info('No standard output returned')

    if len(err) > 0:
        _logger.info("Standard errors:\n\n%s\n" % err)
    else:
        _logger.info('No standard error returned')

    if strict and p.returncode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError('Execution returned non-zero code %d' % p.returncode)

    return p.returncode, out, err
```

I run it using something like:

```
run_cmd("find /data -name 'test*' -mmin -120")
```

Comment: People can't really help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: Point taken, thanks!

Comment: Does unix support quoting with single quote characters (i.e. `'`)? Suggest you stick to double quotes (`"`) — change your call to something like `run_cmd('find /data -name "test*" -mmin -120')`.

Comment: Double quotes do not work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like shell=True does the trick.

```
def validate_cmd_type(cmd):
    """
    Runs a command validator and returns a command ready to be consumed by Popen

    :param cmd: system command to be validated
    :return: return cmd
    :raises Exception if the command is not valid
    """

    if isinstance(cmd, str):
        _logger.info('Valid command - Running command: %s', cmd)
        cmd = cmd.split(' ')
    elif isinstance(cmd, list):
        _logger.info('Valid command - Running command: %s', " ".join(cmd))

    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid command - The command type needs to be a str or list')

    return cmd


def run_cmd(cmd, strict=True, shell=False):
    """
    Runs a system command and returns the return code, stdout and stderr.

    :param cmd: system command to be run
    :param strict: throws error if set else return silently
    :return: return code, stdout, stderr
    :raises ValueError if execution fails
    """

    if not shell:
        cmd = validate_cmd_type(cmd)

    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=shell)

    (out, err) = p.communicate()

    out = '\n'.join(out.decode("utf-8").split('\n'))
    err = '\n'.join(err.decode("utf-8").split('\n'))

    _logger.info("returned code = %d" % p.returncode)

    if len(out) > 0:
        _logger.info("Standard output:\n\n%s\n" % out)
    else:
        _logger.info('No standard output returned')

    if len(err) > 0:
        _logger.info("Standard errors:\n\n%s\n" % err)
    else:
        _logger.info('No standard error returned')

    if strict and p.returncode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError('Execution returned non-zero code %d' % p.returncode)

    return p.returncode, out, err
```